# CASE and IN usage in Sql WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm working on a report and due to a difference in gradings at dataset, I need to be flexible according to parameters.

I want null or graded results only. So a normal where clause would be `(x is null or x in (1,2,3))`

When I try to implement it inside a `CASE WHEN`, I get syntax errors,

Below is what I tried, this is just trying the dataset part so I wont be hardcoding parameter value after this part

```
DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(30)
set @Type = foo

select COUNT(A) as A,B,C
FROM Activity act
    inner join x
    inner join v
    inner join  y
    inner join  z
where 1=1
and DetailKey = @Type
and cd.Value is null or IN
      CASE @Type 
         WHEN  'foo' THEN ('1','2','3') ELSE 
         WHEN  'bar' THEN ('YR','OR','DR') END
```

EDIT: Joins are omitted at the example for shortness, they are not the problem.

Comment: then can you post the full query so that we can point out where is wrong ?

Comment: your CASE WHEN syntax is wrong also

Comment: What is the meaning of `1=1`? This just adds processing time to no benefit.

Comment: 1=1 makes it easier for me while testing among many different where clauses. No real benefit on actual code really.

Comment: Be clear - `CASE` is an *expression*. It produces a *scalar value* (per row). It doesn't let you arbitrarily reconstruct the structure of an SQL statement.

Comment: @ege don't leave `1=1` in production code. It's unneeded overhead (which **does** slow your query down).

Comment: @Larnu I'm aware of the issue, thanks for your concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to have a list of values as the predicate of a `CASE` expression.  But you can rephrase your `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
WHERE
    1 = 1 AND       -- not sure if this is needed
    DetailKey = @Type AND
    (cd.Value IS NULL OR
     (@Type = 'foo' AND cd.Value IN ('1','2','3')) OR
     (@Type = 'bar' AND cd.Value IN ('YR', 'OR', 'DR')))
```